# Looking for sci-fi/ apocalypse movie

Tags: story-identification, movie

Been having multiple obscure movie nights with my jail broken Firestick. One popped into mind and its vehicle related. It's NOT Damnation Alley, Battletruck or Spacehunter. All I can recall is is more apocalypse based and it has a weird black SUV that makes even weirder sounds (imagine Knightrider)  as it drives around thru the wasteland. I've googled my tail off trying to even find a pic of it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: While we will do our best, there's not much to go on. Can you remember anything else: release date, gender of protagonist, etc.?

Comment: I'd say late 70's early 80's. Cheesy male hero Mad Max esq.

Comment: I just found it.  Metalstorm: The Destruction of Jared-Syn. Took me the better part of a week. Obscure indeed!

Comment: Please write your own answer, then! You'll be able to help future visitors to the site, some of whom might have the same question as you.

Comment: Understood. I'm a first timer that stumbled onto the awesomeness of this site! Give me time.